# WiFi not working ubuntu 18

Tags: internet-connection

I am using dell Inspiron 15 3542 and I am facing this issue with wifi, it works fine for few minutes and then icon turns into ? And internet doesn't work. I have tried few fixes but nothing worked. I even made a fresh reinstall because it was working fine before, it's been few days since I started facing this issue

Comment: If it works for awhile and then stops working, I would suspect a hardware problem.

Comment: I don't think so, I have tried using external adapter but still doesn't work @fixer1234

Comment: Have you tested it under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from a live USB? If that works, and continues to work, you've narrowed it down to a specific v. 18.04 issue, e.g. drivers.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik when I reinstalled Ubuntu I checked the option to download other programs like vlc etc and it successfully downloaded the packages but after I logged in from installed os it stopped working.

Comment: 16.04 Live? not installed?